# Passwordless SSH access not working with rejected message

Tags: ssh, rhel, chroot

I setup SSH passwordless  access between two Linux hosts.  But passwordless access is not working. Authentication is cancelled with a rejected message as shown below

```
  su - wsync
 -bash-4.1$ ssh node-x3
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
  debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: Sending environment.
 debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
 Rejected
 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
 Connection to node-x3 closed.
 Transferred: sent 2760, received 3504 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
 Bytes per second: sent 5997.7, received 7614.5
 debug1: Exit status 0
```

Following can be seen on `/var/log/secure` on destination host

```
Jul  1 18:49:23 syd-fs-x3 sshd[17261]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user wsync by (uid=0)
Jul  1 18:49:23 syd-fs-x3 sshd[17266]: error: open /dev/tty failed - could not set controlling tty: Permission denied
Jul  1 18:49:24 syd-fs-x3 sshd[17265]: Received disconnect from 10.200.X.X: 11: disconnected by user
Jul  1 18:49:24 syd-fs-x3 sshd[17261]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user wsync
```

`wsync` user is chroot on destination host

```
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/chroot/home/wsync

 $ ls -l /home/chroot/dev/tty
 crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Nov 30  2015 /home/chroot/dev/tty
```

Following settings for `wsync` user on destination host.

```
     $ sudo grep -A 2 wsync /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      Match User wsync
      ChrootDirectory /home/chroot
      ForceCommand /home/bin/validate-rsync.sh
```

`/etc/securetty` output as requested

```
$ sudo grep tty /etc/securetty
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
tty10
tty11
```

Please let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: What if you use `-T` with `ssh`?

Comment: Same rejected with -T option

Comment: can you please post permission of `/dev/tty` ? and also see `/etc/securetty` if any of the `/dev/tty`s are commented out ?

Comment: Posted /etc/securetty. tty's are not commented

Comment: and can you please post your whole `sshd_config` file please

Comment: Looks like your chroot environment isn't sufficiently set up for an interactive session. Have you got the pts devices, for example?

Comment: A simple ```ssh -v``` or ```ssh -vv``` will help us better.

Comment: updated with ssh -v